# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework - Access navigation properties on parameter model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, asp.net-web-api, navigation-properties

I'm using ASP.NET WebAPI, and in my controller I have a method called `PostAddToGroup`, taking parameters `int id` and `Group group`. On my `Group` entity I have a navigation property called `Members`.

What I want to do is something like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostAddToGroup(int id, Group group) {
    group.Members.Add(id);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

instead of

```
Group _group = db.Groups.Include(x => x.Members).Single(x => 
    x.PosterID == group.PosterID && x.Type == group.Type);
_group.Members.Add(id);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is this possible, and if not, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't see the issue here...the function PostAddToGroup doesn't work? Is the group object valid?

Comment: It works, but it's rather inefficient, as if I was working with pure SQL I wouldn't need to fetch the `Group` row before I update it. I'd rather avoid making unnecessary database calls.

Comment: I am confused, what type is the `group` variable in `Group _group = db.Groups.Find(group.PosterID, group.Type);`?

Comment: It's the same `group` from the first code snippet, I just didn't re-write the method signature.

Comment: Maybe I get it totally wrong but the second code snippet could be simplify like this: `group.Members.Add(id); db.SaveChanges();`no?

Comment: My bad, I forgot a part... take a look at the first line in the second snippet again. The `Members` property is not populated in the `group` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out on my own. All I had to do was attack the model to the DbContext, like so: `db.Groups.Attach(group).Members.Add(id);`